# Как узнать cms сайта с помощью скрипта (Python)

Tags: python, cms

Хочу как-то автоматизировано узнавать cms списка сайтов

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте с помощью библиотеки **CMSMap** https://github.com/Dionach/CMSmap